# Want to understand between previous api creating system vs api creating system using app router in nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, next.js13

page/app/api/code.js

```
export const handler = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ messaage: "successful" });
}
```

But in app router system

app/api/code/route.js

```
export const POST = async (req, res) => {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({
    messaage: "successful"
  }), { 
    status: 201 
  });
}
```

`res` does not work instead I have to use return new Response(JSON.stringify({
messaage: "successful"
}), {
status: 201
}); - but why?

Comment: Because Next.js is different from Express.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is not correct:

```
// GET accepts only req. NO "res"
export const GET = async (req, res) => {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({
    messaage: "successful"
  }), { 
    status: 201 
  });
}
```

new syntax is similar to `sveltekit`. with `new Response` we are creating a response object manually so we are not coupled to a server. so it will be easier to test the app.

New api is much simpler and claimed to have faster performance. It might be better integrated with other Next.js features and functionalities to increase the benefits